# Error in getting file using sharepoint designer 2010 programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Error in getting file using sharepoint designer 2010 programmatically

```
protected void updateTemplate_1()
{
        SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb();
        string FilePath = "";   

        try
          {
            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPListItemCollection  listItems  = spWeb.Lists["Captive Report"].Items;
            string sitecol= spSite.Url.ToString().Trim();

              foreach(SPListItem lst11 in listItems)
                {
                       FilePath=lst11.Url.ToString().Trim(); //Gets the site-relative URL of the item
                }
                SPFile file = spWeb.GetFile(FilePath);                                       
                System.IO.FileInfo templateFile = new  System.IO.FileInfo(@FilePath);

      using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(templateFile))   //OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(result, source)
        {
        int count = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Count;
        Response.Write(count+"<br>");

              byte[] fileBytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();  
              //byte[] fileBytes = file.OpenBinary();
                    Response.Clear();
                 Response.ClearContent();
                 Response.ClearHeaders();
                 Response.Cookies.Clear();
                 //Add the header & other information                 
                 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
                 Response.CacheControl = "private";
                 Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
                 Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
                 Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "cache");
                 Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "60");

                string filename = "fileName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM").Trim();// +".xlsx";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; " +
                "filename=\"" + filename + ".xlsx\"; "    //filename of excel   

                 );

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                //Write it back to the client                
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);  
                }
           }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
```

}

The workbook that I am trying to fetch has 3 worksheets,still 
This is giving worksheet count as Zero (0),
and hence while converting using GetAsByteArray, its showing error as :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The workbook must contain at least
>   one worksheet at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save() at
>   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray(Boolean save) at

Comment: SharePoint Designer is a desktop application, you can't use it "programmatically". As for the error, it isn't related to SharePoint. The error is *very* cleare - you tried to create an Excel file without any worksheets. If you check the `count`variable, you'll find it's 0. Does `FilePath` point to a valid *local file*? Did you mean to use the `file` contents instead?

Comment: Apart from that, the code doesn't make much sense. You iterate over all items yet only use the *last* FilePath. You attempt to create an Excel file from a template, yet never put anything in it. What are you trying to do? If you wanted to send a document to the client, why don't you simply redirect the client to the document's URL? Or just send the file's contents?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.Yes, I agree that SharePoint Designer is desktop application, but for some of our requirement we have made it programmatically . Its confirm that excel file is not empty, it has 3 worksheets.  And I cant redirect it to client because once I get the count of worksheet more than zero, I need to make changes in that excel and then save it back. I hope this info can help .

Comment: Not really, because the error contradicts what you say. First, this code can only run on SharePoint server - SharePoint designer is *not* programmable.  Second, what file are you *really* loading? Your code would *only* work if FilePath was a path *of a local server file*, or at least  a file on a network share. It would *not* work if FilePath pointed to a document stored in SharePoint. So what Excel file did you check to confirm that there are sheets? As for redirecting and checking - you don't check anything  right now. The error is **very** clear. You are trying to send an empty file

Comment: If I avoid using OpenOfficeXml in this code and simply open the file, I am able to download it.If the file is empty, how I am able to download it? A similar problem is comming when I am trying it in visual studio web part.